# Apache POI Excel shows only data label and cut chart

Tags: java, apache-poi

Question 1. I just show only data labels on the bar chart.

Question 2. The chart is cut the bar. The first category and the last category.

[image]

You can see mixed labels, 'right axis' + 'bottom axis' + 'data value'.

I want to see only the data labels.

I want to display three of bottom of category '1'. And also three of bottom of category '64'.

How can I do this?

Language - Java

Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I referenced here.
(https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BarChart.java)

```
private void createChart(XSSFSheet sheet,
                         String chartTitle,
                         String leftTitle,
                         String bottomAxisTitle,
                         List<Map<String, Object>> reportData,
                         Map<String, String> capMap,
                         String rwRatio,
                         String resultType,
                         String name,
                         Integer startRownum,
                         Integer startCellIndex,
                         Integer lastRownum,
                         Integer lastCellIndex) {

    XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(
        10, 10, 110, 110, startCellIndex,
        startRownum, lastCellIndex, lastRownum); //int dx1, int dy1, int dx2,
                                                 //int dy2, int col1, int row1,
                                                 //int col2, int row2

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

    chart.setTitleText(chartTitle);
    chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

    // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
    XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setTitle(bottomAxisTitle);

    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setTitle(leftTitle);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis); // Chart type

    XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(qdList);
    String title = "";

    for(Map<String, Object> report : reportData) {
        List <Double>iops = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Map<String, Object>> fios = (List<Map<String, Object>>) report.get("myData");
        TestMain tm =  (TestMain) report.get("testMain");
        title = capMap.get(tm.getId().toString());
        for(String qd : qdList) {
            for(Map<String, Object> fio : fios) {
                iops.add(Double.parseDouble(fio.get(name).toString()));
            }
        }

        Double [] values = new Double[iops.size()];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < iops.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = iops.get(i);
        }

        XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);
        XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);

        series1.setTitle(title, null);
        series1.setShowLeaderLines(true);

    }

    chart.plot(data);
    chart.displayBlanksAs(DisplayBlanks.SPAN);

    XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
    bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);

    List<PresetColor> color = colors();
    for(int idx = 0 ; idx < reportData.size() ; idx++) {
        solidFillSeries(data, idx, color.get(idx));
    }


private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {

    XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
    XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
    XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
    if (properties == null) {
        properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
    }
    properties.setFillProperties(fill);
    series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    series.setShowLeaderLines(true);
}
```

Comment: Let the left axis cross the bottom axis between the category marks: `leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);`. The default is left axis crosses the bottom axis midpoint the category marks. This is what your screenshot shows.

Comment: @AxelRichter !!!!!!! Thanks!!!! (removed my comment, so again)

Answer (score 0):

I found the first answer!!!

1. I added a dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I added some code.

   ```
   int seriesNr = 0;

   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.CTR);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(seriesNr).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);

   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getDLbls().addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.CTR);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
   ```

Here is the changed chart image.

[image]

`seriesNr` is data of index `getSerArray(seriesNr)`.